# cin.ignore() works strangely in c++

Tags: c++

I am new at c++ and this function is giving me some problems. When doing the cin.ignore() the program asks for some input, and when I hit enter, nothing else happens, the program stays there. n is always 9 and c is an array with less than 9 characters.

```
void LeerCadena(char *c, int n) {
    while (1) {
        cin.getline(c, n);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Introduce un dato valido" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `std::string` rather than raw character arrays here. They’re much safer.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that this is a project for the uni and I have to do it both using a string and an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't know how you want to read data exactly. But you program do this,

- when line shorter or equal to n ('\n' does count). Line is read and one line below is read and ignored and value and work is done.
- In case the line is longer, then fail flag is set in cin object and cin.ignore() is ignored. Then cin is cleared (all flags are down) and that longer line is ignored. And loop does continue.

So program does waiting for line which is shorter then n characters. And ignore one line after it.

### Problems

If new line character is missing, it will be forever cycling. The stream have 3 flags that means stream is broken. Failbit, eofbit, and badbit. 
cin.good() gives none of these bits is true.

So !cin.good() looks better then cin.fail(), but it is not too easy. In case eof, clean() and ignore() gives you another eof. So it could be like that.

```
void LeerCadena(char *c, int n) {
    while (1) {
        cin.getline(c, n);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Introduce un dato valido" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } else if(!cin.good()){
            cerr << "LeerCadena failed!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else return;
    }
}
```

But you don't know which of functions failed whether getline or ignore.

I really recommend you make getline and then asks what happened. Why you need ignore after getline?

TIP: I also recommend you to create input files and redirect file on standard input of program from command line.